# Такой юный и уже калека

Tags: пунктуация

**"Такой юный( ) и уже калека".**
Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении?
В разговорной речи, как мне кажется, часто говорится именно с частицей "и". Значит, запятая не нужна?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь подойдет тире.

Comment: Здесь имеется неожиданное присоединение, поэтому знак препинания нужен, лучше тире.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, здесь редкий случай, когда союз "и" употребляется в значении "а" "или "но"